# Regex to find words that are not followed by letter

Tags: php, regex

I am looping over a text string (in php) to change certain keywords in a database into links. The problem is when words in the database exist within each other such as:

develop, developer, development...

I end up with:

```
"Random string with the word <a href="developer"><a href="develop">develop</a>er</a> in it"
```

I would need this to only wrap an a tag around **developer** and not the **develop** within it...

Here is my current function:

```
function hyper($haystack){ 
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `hyperwords` ";  
    $query .= "WHERE `active` = '1' ";
    $query .= "ORDER BY LENGTH(hyperword) DESC ";  
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $needle = $row['hyperword'];
        $link = $row['link'];
        $haystack = preg_replace("/($needle)/iu", "<a class='meta' href='$link'>$1</a>", $haystack);
    }
    return $haystack;
}
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: This extends beyond checking if they are followed by a letter what about cases where a word is within another word... e.g. another and not. Does it need to be on partial words? Or should it only link full words.

Comment: @Jacob - The client did not specify, I am assuming full words only. But a very good point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$altered = preg_replace("/\b($needle)\b/iu", "<a class='meta' href='$link'>$1</a>", $altered);
```

is what you need :)

> The metacharacter **\b** is an anchor like
>   the caret and the dollar sign. It
>   matches at a position that is called a
>   "word boundary". This match is
>   zero-length.

see [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) for more information :)